# Prometheus "read: connection reset by peer"

Tags: prometheus, telegraf

I have three Windows servers that I am trying to get metrics from, I'm using Telegraf with a Prometheus plugin to scrape the metrics from a "/metrics" endpoint. I previously had three Windows servers using the same configuration, that are reporting as expected. I also have several other servers both Linux and Windows that are working and reporting metrics to my instance of Grafana. My new servers keep getting this error. What does this mean?

`Get http://xx.xx.xx.67:9273/metrics: read tcp xx.xx.xx.46:48954->xx.xx.xx.67:9273: read: connection reset by peer`

[These are the metrics on the endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqbnz.png)

[Prometheus Dashboard? Where all the Targets are.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax8En.png)

Comment: The connection is refused (it may expect https or the firewall actively refuses it). Did you try curl to request the metrics ?

Comment: I expect you kept the config `listen = ":9273"` to bind on all interfaces. Try another exporter (wmi_exporter) to check if it is a telegraf or a windows issue

Comment: Also, try locally on a windows server with a navigator.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez Can you explain the on Windows server with navigator? Do you mean with browser? and using the localhost endpoint?

Comment: Yes. Using a browser ('scuse my french)

Comment: I put `http://xx.xx.xx.67:9273/metrics` in my browsers URL and it takes me to the endpoint where all the metrics are. They're all there. I can even access them on a different computer on the network, that's what frustrating, is I know they are there  on the endpoint but Prometheus is acting like it can't get to them. I just added a picture of the metrics on the endpoint. It's up above.